# How can you evenly rotate header(location) URLs?

Tags: php

I'm looking to perform split testing between 3 different pages.

I'm using a uber simple rotate.php file as my index that doesn't yet have a rotate ability. Here is what it contains:

```
<?php header('Location: http://stackoverflow.com');?>
```

How can I add more URLs, then evenly rotate between them?

Comment: I'm really curious why this was downvoted, and voted to be closed as "not a real question".  This is one of the best questions I've read all day.  How is this not a real question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking to A/B/C test these pages and you use Google Analytics,  I'd recommend looking into [Google Website Optimizer](http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/3203-Using-Google-Website-Optimizer-for-A-B-Testing).

If you still want to do it on your own, you can use something like Brad's answer. However, if you want a decent result, don't forget to cookie the user and make sure you send them to the same page each time. For example:

```
$pages = array(
     1 => 'http://stackoverflow.com',
     2 => 'http://google.com'
);
if (isset($_COOKIE['testpage']) && isset($pages[$_COOKIE['testpage']])) {
    $page = $pages[$_COOKIE['testpage']];
} else {
    $page = array_rand($pages);
    setcookie('testpage', $page, ...);
    $page = $pages[$page];
}
header('Location: ' . $page);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest making an array of URLs, and randomly picking one.

```
$urls = array(
    'http://stackoverflow.com',
    'http://google.com'
);
header('Location: ' . $urls[array_rand($urls)]);
```